# How to render react page to user with Express backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have my **node/express** server running on `http://localhost:3000/`

I am handling post request (from some client **http://example.com**) hitting on my node server, I am handling it using express router.

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  let empid = req.body.empid;
  let depid = req.body.depid;
  let empdetails = //Fetch data from DB by passing empid & depid
  res.send(empdetails);
});
```

In the last step, instead of sending empdetails to the client submitted post request, I want to display the employee details using my **react** app running on `http://localhost:5000/` by passing empdetails to react page.

> How to achieve this? Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking how to render the initial page that includes your react app? Or are you asking how to query your server to get data?

Comment: @Cully My initial POST request will not be from react page. It will come from a normal HTML client using form submit. But I want to render the result using react.

Comment: Rest API's are not bidirectional, client/React app needs to send a request to start the conversation or fetch the data. However, If you want to implement your described requirement then you will have to use [Sockets](https://socket.io/) using which you can send the data to the react app without an get request.

Comment: So you might have one user submitting data using a form on one page and you want to display that data to another user viewing another page? Your second page will have to use sockets or polling.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views it does exactly what you want

Comment: @C.Gochev let me try this and will update. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @WilliamBrain, did you find any solution for this? I am facing the exact same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to get the data from the backend, from a router you set for `get` request, and map it to the UI with react, for example, design a get request in your node server:

```
router.get("/api/empdetails", (req, res) => {
  EmpDetails.find()
    .then(EmpDetails=> res.json(EmpDetails))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ err:err }));
});  // for example from a mongodb server getting data with mongoose
```

then in front-end, in your react component:

```
import axios from "axios"

state={
 empDetails:[]    
  }

componentDidMount() {
     axios
    .get("http://localhost:3000/api/empdetails")
    .then(res => 
      this.setState({empDetails:res.data})
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
render(){
const {empDetails} = this.state
let empDetailsMarkup = empDetails ? (empDetails.map(empDetail => {  
 <p>empDetail.name</p> })) : null // assuming there is a name for each empDetail and this will print it to the screen
  return(<div>{empDetails}</div>)

}
```

Comment: How do I handle POST data in React and pass that POST data to  axios
    .get("http://localhost:3000/api/empdetails")

Comment: In my example, you post your data from an html page or whatever to the node.js backend server, after then, with a router.get function in node.js you set a get request. In your react component, with componentDidMount you get this data via axios and set it to your components state.

Comment: But when my html page POST details to node.js server, res.json(EmpDetails) will send the response to html page. How do we then establish connection between nodejs & react page?